# Parallel Update Management - Azure

Tags: azure, azure-automation

Im deploying Updates in Azure to 30 VMs and my doubt is if they are being installing in parallel or serial. Im deploying by Automation Account

I think that when finishes one machine starts the next one

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you doing the updates?

Comment: David, im deplying it by automation account

Comment: any ideas??????